# Issue using Export Import API Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013, api, importexportservice

i was trying to create a console application so i could take an export package using the API(http://erichuiza.blogspot.nl/2013/12/tridion-2013-sp1-api-improvements.html)
I have this code:

```
ImportExportServiceClient client = new ImportExportServiceClient();
   ReadFromTxt txtObject= new ReadFromTxt();
   Selection[]  selection = txtObject.fetchList();
   ExportInstruction instruction = new ExportInstruction { LogLevel = LogLevel.Normal };
   string processId = client.StartExport(selection, instruction);
```

This gives me the error

*Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an er
ror while trying to serialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager
/ImportExport/2013:selections. The InnerException message was 'Type 'ExportImpor
tBusiness.implementSelection' with data contract name 'implementSelection:http:/
/schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ExportImportBusiness' is not expected. Conside
r using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list
of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by a
dding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'*

This breaks at **client.StartExport**.
**ExportImportBusiness** is the namespace of my business  class.
The method **ReadFromTxt()** returns an array of Selection. It reads from a text file containing TCM-ids, 1 in a row.

Code from ReadFromTxt

```
public class ReadFromTxt
    {

        public Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Selection[] fetchList()
        {
            Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Selection[] a = null; ;
            a = populateArray(a);
            Console.WriteLine("After populating Array");
            Console.WriteLine(a[0].ToString());
            return a;
        }


        public Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Selection[] populateArray(Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Selection[] a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside method populateArray. About to populate Array");
            string filePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
            Console.WriteLine("Value of variable file is" +filePath);
            int count = File.ReadLines(filePath).Count();
            a = InitializeArray<implementSelection>(count, filePath);
            return a;
        }

        public implementSelection[] InitializeArray<T>(int length, string filePath) where T : new()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside method InitializeArray ");
            implementSelection[] array = new implementSelection[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                string line = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(i - 1).Take(1).First();
                //T item = new T();
                implementSelection item = new implementSelection(line);
               // item.field = line;
                array[i] = item;
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(array.GetType());
            return array;
        }



        public ProcessState WaitForProcessFinish(ImportExportServiceClient client, string processId)
        {
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ProcessState? processState = client.GetProcessState(processId);
                if (processState == ProcessState.Finished || processState == ProcessState.Aborted || processState == ProcessState.AbortedByUser)
                {
                    return processState.Value;
                }
            }

            while (true);
        }


        public void DownloadPackage(string processId, string packageLocation)
        {
            var downloadClient = new ImportExportStreamDownloadClient();
            // downloadClient.DownloadProcessLogFile(processId, true) to download log file
            using (var packageStream = downloadClient.DownloadPackage(processId, deleteFromServerAfterDownload: true))
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(packageLocation))
                {
                    packageStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And i have used the **Selection** class as below:

```
public class implementSelection : Selection
    {
        public implementSelection()
        { }

        public implementSelection(string value)
        {
            field = value;
        }

        public string field = "abdc";
        public override string ToString()
        {

            return field;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you exporting? what fetchList() is returning? can you post in your question.

Comment: could you share signature and code of ReadFromTxt() it seems this method returning some reference to your namespace also, which is being reported as exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selection is a parent class of selections for Export, such as GroupsSelection, SubtreeSelection, etc. More about selections you can read in following blog: http://tridioninternals.blogspot.nl/2014/01/selecting-items-to-export.html

In your case I suspect you want to export list of tcm-uris or webdav urls, which you read from file. In this case you should use ItemsSelection and your code will look like:

```
string[] array = { "tcm:0-1-1", "/webdav/Publication" }; //array which you read from file   
Selection[] selection = { new ItemsSelection { ItemIds = array } };
```

Comment: Hi, the function ReadFromTxt() returns an array of Selection. It reads from a text file containing TCM-ids, 1 in a row.

Comment: I looks like your code also have a Selection class, which is also declared in ImportExportClient. I thinks it might be incorrectly recognized in your program from which place to get this class. Can you try to directly put namespace before your class?

Comment: Hi, i updated it as                                                                                  public class implementSelection : Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Selection                                          but the error is same. I did F12 before change and it was going to right definition.

Comment: Why do you need to re-implement Selection class in first place? It will case a data contact break, because new properties can not be deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

so `public class implementSelection : Selection`is your custom class in your mentioned namespace.

That's the reason your are getting serialization error. No aliens. so you need to update you code. remove your `implementSelection` class.

Update your code as per following Sample Code

```
public IEnumerable<string>InitializeArray(int length, string filePath)
        {
        }
public IEnumerable<string> populateArray()
        {
        }

public IEnumerable<string> fetchList(){}


var client = new ImportExportServiceClient();
var txtObject= new ReadFromTxt();
var itemLists=  txtObject.fetchList();

var selection = new[] { new ItemsSelection(itemsList) };
```